# when to use gdx.files.internal and when relative path?

Tags: android, file, path, libgdx, assets

I've seen many examples of both cases, for example:

```
atlas = new TextureAtlas("skins/userInterface.pack");
white = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("font/white.fnt"));
```

I've seen that on a tutorial but, it also works that way:

```
atlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("skins/userInterface.pack"));
white = new BitmapFont("font/white.fnt");
```

when should I use Gdx.files.internal or directly the relative path from assets folder?

Comment: It is exactly the same. When using a String only, the method does the same internally.

Comment: @noone thank you, if you put it as an answer I'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is exactly the same. When using a `String` parameter, the constructor uses `Gdx.files.internal` to resolve the file, just as you would do it yourself.

You can see this [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/TextureAtlas.java#L211) for example in case of the `TextureAtlas`.

Comment: what happens with: white = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("font/white.fnt"));

and white = new BitmapFont("font/white.fnt");

or the same with sprites, is it the same than texture atlas?

Comment: Sure, everywhere where you can use Strings, libgdx assumes it to be an internal path.